# Add fields of another model in Django's built-in LoginView for Login

Tags: python, django

I want to make a login system, in this I want to use "Company Name", "User name", and "Password" for login, can I customize it with Django built-in `LoginView`? "Company name" is Company model field.
Here is my Company Model:

```
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
     company_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     pin_code = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

[image: "This is my Login Screen"]

Comment: [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) Check the documentation, for this case you could extend the user model